# Geo-location points android and Accuracy

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, location, android-location

I have a very complicated problem and hope anyone can help me

I am building android application that track user movement in some specific predefined points, and I want to report the arrival and leaving of user to and from these points.

The problem is I am using distanceTo method to get the distance between current user place and location come from location service, to be able to know if the user arrive or left

but the accuracy is a big problem here, some times it is "10" and some other times it is "60" based on the best provider of my gps service, so the user is reporting arrive and leave many times from the same place.

Can any one help me ??

Comment: I think it depend on how you are fetching the location. GPS based locations are always accurate, but, if you are fetching location from network provider, those are not very accurate.

Comment: Yes it give me "10" when using gps , and "60" when using network and I need to handle them all.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "10" and "60", but, I can only tell you that if you want precision, you need to retrieve location through GPS only and you need to ditch getting location from network provider.

Comment: "10" and "60" is the accuracy of each provider, and I need also to be able to find user place even if the user is indoor and can't fetch location using gps.

Comment: I think you can only use getAccuracy () method of Location class. When the returned value from that method reachs the required accuracy, you can start to do what you want. For example, if your gps give you a positon, and getAccuracy() retruns 50, you can discard this value, and wait for another gps value, with more accuracy

Answer (score 2):

Using location.GetAccuracy() is a good way to go about it. You can filter out gps data that doesn't meet your requirements. Please note that getting 10 meter accuracy all the time is highly unlikely, in my experience 10 meters is about the best you can get. Do it like this:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        // discard any location greater than 20 meters
        if (location.getAccuracy() < 20.0f) {
            // use your location data here
        }
    }
}
```

You can see a full working sample in my open source Gps Tracker project:

https://github.com/nickfox/GpsTracker/blob/master/phoneClients/android/app/src/main/java/com/websmithing/gpstracker/LocationService.java